# accept() functions is acting as non-blocking

Tags: c++, sockets, winsock

I am writing a server program using Winsock that waits for the client connection. The code is like this:

```
#include <winsock.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "wsock32.lib")

WSADATA wsaData;
WSAStartup(0x101, &wsaData);
SOCKET listeningSocket;
listeningSocket = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,IPPROTO_TCP);

SOCKADDR_IN serverInfo;
serverInfo.sin_family = AF_INET;
serverInfo.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
serverInfo.sin_port = htons(80);

bind(listeningSocket, (LPSOCKADDR)&serverInfo, sizeof(struct sockaddr));
listen(listeningSocket, 5);

SOCKET theClient;
while(true)
{
    theClient = accept(listeningSocket,NULL,NULL);
    ....
    recv(theClient,Message,strlen(Message),0);
    ....
    ....
}
```

The problem I am having is that server does not wait for the client and continues execution after accept() function. Specifically, accept() function is not blocking the execution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check the return values from all the library functions. It could be that an early call (e.g. `bind()`) is failing, but you never find out since you are ignoring the return value.

Comment: You are right !!! `bind()` is not working. Can you please tell what is the problem?

Comment: @Faheem: Look at the error code. There are several possible reasons (e.g. there could be something already listening on port 80).

Comment: Looks like that is the problem. When I changed the port to some large value, it works fine. But I have to use port 80. This is a necessary requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Try printing out the error message on accept and it might help with the issue you're having (you should also do this with bind.)

bind error checking:

```
int result; 
result = bind(listeningSocket, (LPSOCKADDR)&serverInfo, sizeof(struct sockaddr));
if (result == SOCKET_ERROR) {
    printf("bind failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
    freeaddrinfo(serverInfo);
    closesocket(listeningSocket);
    WSACleanup();
    return 1;
}
```

accept error checking:

```
theClient = INVALID_SOCKET;

// Accept a client socket
theClient = accept(listeningSocket, NULL, NULL);
if (theClient == INVALID_SOCKET) {
    printf("accept failed: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
    closesocket(listeningSocket);
    WSACleanup();
    return 1;
}
```

for more info, look at:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/windows/desktop/ms737593(v=vs.85).aspx

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb530751(v=vs.85).aspx